# redirect domain to app server works. but not "www"

Tags: domain-name-system, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

I have set my A record for "example.com" to my app server.
and I have a CNAME "www" that points to example.com

with this configuration, if I go to my domain without www, it works perfect. but without www, it gives me the default app server page.

do i have to make an extra virtual host for just the "www" in passenger?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

With most web servers, it's either an additional virtual domain or configuring the a virtual domain to also answer to the combination (some also have the capabilities to define wildcards as well).